# Error when trying to send data to CouchDB database

Tags: objective-c, json, couchdb

When I try to run this code to send data to my CouchDB database, I got the error:

> 2015-06-04 15:30:43.426 ddd[8303:640525] requestReply: {"error":"bad_request","reason":"Referer header required."}

Anyway I can fix this?

```
- (IBAction)sendDataToJson:(id)sender

{
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:5984/sgram/cc362033a500f51767fbc87efc0003ae"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
    NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the verb `PUT` instead of `POST`.